# get all hitids of a requester in Mturk workersandbox

Tags: list, mechanicalturk

I want to list all the HITId of created HITs in **Mturk Worker sandbox**.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

On the API you can use a `SearchHITs` operation to retrieve the HITIds for all HITs.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_SearchHITsOperation.html